# Why is it impossible to run virtual box additions .run file?

Tags: debian, virtualbox

Last time I was installing Debian + XFCE on Virtual Box everything went smooth, including virtual box additions which were installed in one click. Since then, the system became much more unfriendly. Apart from the freaky allways broken system panels (xfce thing) I seem suddenly unable to execute run files.

This is what the virtual CD-ROM installer looks like:

[image: image description]

As you can see the `.run` file doesn't behave as executable. What's more horrible is that even terminal approach doesn't work:

[image: image description]

This really sucks. I thought after typping sudo, permissions cease to mean anything. So what am I supposed to do in this new Debian?

Comment: What does `ls -l /media/cdrom0/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` show and what does `mount | grep cdrom0` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the executable bit is not set.  If it is not, then you can not run the file.  The options in the file manger should include run if the executable bit is set.  Being root does not bypass this requirement.  If the script is a shell (bash or sh), you should be able to run it with a command like `sudo bash /media/cdrom0/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`.

Comment: Although this works, I do not think you should proceed with your method. There is no need to spawn another bash process to run something that could simply be marked executable.

Comment: In was unable to mark it as executable because it was on readonly CD drive. I ran it through `sh` which most resembles this answer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to copy the CDROM to disk and execute there.

Comment: Don't understand the downvote. This method totally worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the file executable.

`chmod +x VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`